Debezium have any tools to rescan table?
I need to ensure that I have all actual data in destination table. I need to rescan table at least one time per day. How to write all rows from table in kafka from debezium for one table?
Example: I have source and destination dbs. With some reason some rows was deleted in destination table. So I need to restore these deleted rows
I tried to use incremental snapshot but this is doesn't work.
Db: PostgreSql
Example: Insert into debezium_signal(id,type,data) value ("3d6b9bf2-4708-435e-bc52-0da429121d39",   "execute-snapshot","{""data-collections"": [""public.guests""]}")
Debezium works, but didn't see any changes
